# Looking to understand proposition related to the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am having some problem understanding exactly what the following proposition is saying. Also, is this result have a common name? How important it is, etc. It is

$\mathbf{Proposition:}$

Let $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_0$$ be a complex non zero polynomial of degree $n$, then

$$f(x)=a_n \prod_{i=1}^n(x-z_i)$$

for suitable complex numbers $z_i$ that need not be distinct, the $z_i$ are all roots of $f$ and any root of $f$ is some $z_i$ , and moreover the factorization is distinct.

Thank you everyone for your time and comments.

Comment: You have called it by its usual name in the title.  Another quick way of stating it is that the complex numbers are an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Oh okay, so this is another way of stating the fundamental theorem? Because my professor said the proof of the FTA was to advance for the course right now, but that for this proposition it was much simpler.

Comment: At what level do you wish to understand this? Do you know about polynomial rings and all that? As for importance, this is more or less why the classical algebraic geometers at some point chose to focus on geometry over $\mathbb{C}$: the algebra (the polynomial, let's say it's monic) and the geometry (the set of zeros, with multiplicities) determine each other.

Comment: It is a first course in Abstract Algebra for undergrad. We havent learnt of polynomial ring yet

Comment: What is often called the FTA is the statement that every non-constant complex polynomial has a complex root -- just do a quick search. That seems even less fancy, so I'm not sure what your instructor was hinting at.

Comment: Yes that is what the FTA he said. He said the proofs are analytic and algebraic and require more then the proof for this which just requires induction

Comment: This is the FTA, and the proof is not easy. Another version of the FTA is that any non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients has a root in the complex numbers. From that lemma you can prove the FTA as stated above quite simply. But proving the lemma is difficult.

Comment: Are you sure it says that the factorization is "distinct"?

Answer (score 0):

It means that over $\mathbf C$, any non-constant polynomial splits as a product of linear factors, and this factorisation is unique (up to order), hence the roots of $f$ are the roots of the linear factors.

They observe that some factors may be repeated, which corresponds to *multiple roots*. The number of factors equal to $x-z_i$ is the *order of multiplicity* of $z_i$.